# Program crashing on free() with an invalid pointer message

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, calloc

I don't know,why I am getting this error:

> Error in `./prog': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0941600b

While executing this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int test;   
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test)
    {
        char *s;
        int count=0;
        s=(char *)calloc(10000,sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",s);
        while(*s)
        {
            if(*s=='W')
                count++;
            s++;
        } 
        printf("%d\n",count);  
        free(s);
        test--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code, you first did

```
 s++;  //moving the actually returned pointer
```

and then, you tried

```
 free(s);  //pass the changed pointer
```

So, once  you're not passing the same pointer which was returned by `calloc()`. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To add, quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.3

> [...] if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

so the `s++` modifies the original pointer which is not the same anymore which was returned by `calloc()` and passing the same to `free()` invokes UB. You need to keep a copy of the original pointer to pass that to `free()` later.

That said,

1. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. You should always check the return value of `calloc()` and family before using the returned value to avoid deferefencing of NULL pointer in case the function call failed.

Comment: Thank You very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You call `free` with the value of `s` after you've incremented it. You need to save the value that you got back from `calloc` so that you can pass it to `free`.

Comment: Thank You very much for your explanation.